How can I account for the value in each order
I have a one table with orders, like this:
orders_data = {
    'date_order': ['2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-02'],
    'order_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'article_id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
    'quantity': [5, 1, 3, 2],
    'final_price': [50, 50, 30, 20],
    'logistics_costs': [10, 10, 5, 4],
    'revenue': [200, 100, 80, 40],
    'cost_price': [30, 30, 20, 15],
    'profit': [160, 70, 60, 25]
}

orders = pd.DataFrame(orders_data)

And a table with advertising costs:
adv_data = {
    'adv_date': ['2024-04-01', '2024-04-02', '2024-04-03'],
    'article_id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'costs': [24, 10, 15]
}

adv = pd.DataFrame(adv_data)

I need to account for the advertising costs for each order (if there is one).
For instance: If I have orders on 2024-04-01 with article_id A  and have advertising cost on 2024-04-01 for article_id A, I will add a column (adv_cost)  with value which looks like: advertising costs / number of each article (quantity) on the date 2024-04-01.
But If I don’t have orders on 2024-04-01 and have advertising cost I will add a row with empty values in all columns except adv_cost.
The desired result is as follows:
result_data = {
    'date_order': ['2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-02', '2024-04-02','2024-04-01'],
    'order_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 'adv_cost', 'adv_cost'],
    'article_id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'quantity': [5, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0],
    'final_price': [50, 50, 30, 20, 0, 0],
    'logistics_costs': [10, 10, 5, 4, 0, 0],
    'revenue': [200, 100, 80, 40, 0, 0],
    'cost_price': [30, 30, 20, 15, 0, 0],
    'profit': [160, 70, 60, 25, 0, 0],
    'adv_cost': [20, 4, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 15.0]
}

result_data = pd.DataFrame(result_data)

For better understanding - visually:


What do you need help with exactly? From a glance, it looks like you just need to merge and groupby-transform.

BTW, if the other columns aren't relevant to the problem (final_price, logistics_costs, revenue, cost_price, profit), you could drop a few for the sake of example. See [mre].

Not exactly, not only groupby-transform. I must divide value for quantity in group. Ok, I will discover what is it

Thnx for -  How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

IIUC, you can use a combination of groupby.transform and merge with a bit of post-processing:
out = (orders
  # compute total quantity per date/id
  .assign(total=orders.groupby(['date_order', 'article_id'])['quantity']
                      .transform('sum'))
  # perform outer merge
  .merge(adv.rename(columns={'adv_date': 'date_order'}),
         how='outer', on=['date_order', 'article_id'])
  # compute and fill data based on empty cells
  .assign(adv_cost=lambda d: d['costs'].div(d['total']).mul(d['quantity'])
                                       .fillna(d['costs']),
          order_id=lambda d: d['order_id'].fillna('adv_cost')
         )
  .drop(columns=['total', 'costs']) # remove temporary columns
  .fillna(0)
)

Output:
   date_order  order_id article_id  quantity  final_price  logistics_costs  revenue  cost_price  profit  adv_cost
0  2024-04-01       1.0          A       5.0         50.0             10.0    200.0        30.0   160.0      20.0
1  2024-04-01       2.0          A       1.0         50.0             10.0    100.0        30.0    70.0       4.0
2  2024-04-01       3.0          B       3.0         30.0              5.0     80.0        20.0    60.0       0.0
3  2024-04-02       4.0          A       2.0         20.0              4.0     40.0        15.0    25.0       0.0
4  2024-04-02  adv_cost          B       0.0          0.0              0.0      0.0         0.0     0.0      10.0
5  2024-04-03  adv_cost          C       0.0          0.0              0.0      0.0         0.0     0.0      15.0


Thanks @mozway for your help! I'll study your decision!

What you need is to use pd.merge() method to join both tables.
I added a little bit of column processing so you can have the data tidier.
    orders_adv_data = pd.merge(left = orders
                              ,right = adv
                              ,left_on = ['date_order','article_id']
                              ,right_on = ['adv_date','article_id']
                              ,how = 'outer')

    columns = orders_adv_data.columns
    orders_adv_data['date'] = orders_adv_data['date_order'].fillna(orders_adv_data['adv_date'])
    column_order = columns.insert(0,'date')
    orders_adv_data = orders_adv_data[column_order]

    orders_adv_data



Please don't post pictures of text, post the text itself and use the formatting tools like code formatting (print(df)) or table formatting (print(df.to_markdown()).

Yeah,  but after that, I need to divide the value (costs) by the number of ordered items on that date. Thnx @DonWizu
